# Webkit JQuery Mobile block to inline Transition Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, webkit

I'm tying to get an orientation change to work on the mobile browsers. When the orientation changes the div "wrapStat" is supposed to change between inline and block display.

This complete block of text is replaced every X seconds by an ajax call so putting a style on the wrapStat class itself will not work. I'm changing the parent #CustomStats class between portraitCustomStats and landscapeCustomStats depending on the orientation.

This works in Firefox (resizing the browser will flip the orientation flag) but does not work in any webkit browser until the ajax call fires.

Is there a problem with webkit and dynamically changing inline and block styles?

css:

```
.portraitCustomStats .StatsRow .wrapStat {
    display: block !important;
}
.landscapeCustomStats .StatsRow .wrapStat {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (anOrientationEvent) {
    if ($(window).width() > 600) return;
    $("#CustomStats").attr("class", anOrientationEvent.orientation.toLowerCase() + "CustomStats").trigger("updatelayout");
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="CustomStats" class="portraitCustomStats">
    <tr class="StatsRow">
      <td class="description">Unique Visitors</td>
        <td class="stat">
          <span class="UniqueVisitors">
            <strong>
            <div class="wrapStat">
              <span class="pastStat">(1,318)</span>
                <img src="../../Images/up_arr.gif" alt="increase">
                <span class="increasedStat">85.43%</span>
            </div>
           </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</span>
```

Here is the jsFiddle of the code actually not working...

http://jsfiddle.net/Hupperware/43eK8/5/

Mobile view: http://jsfiddle.net/m/rat/

This works in Firefox (text turns red in "landscape" and blue in "portrait" just so you know it's working). In FF it will show inline and block as you go between a wider view and a narrow view...

In Webkit (Safari and Chrome) it will not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've found the answer...

Original:

```
<tr class="StatsRow">
     <td class="description">Total Sales</td>
     <td class="stat">
          <span class="TotalSalesRow">
               <strong>$59,549.16</strong>
               <div class="wrapStat">
                    <span class="pastStat">($59,799.66)</span>
                    <img src="https://portal.thesba.com/Images/down_arr.gif" alt="decrease">
                    <span class="decreasedStat">0.42%</span>
               </div>
          </span>
      </td>
</tr>
```

It appears that having a span wrap a div causes undesirable action in webkit when you try to change the layout on the containing div.

Change: (div tag below 2nd td)

```
<tr class="StatsRow">
     <td class="description">Total Sales</td>
     <td class="stat">
          <div class="TotalSalesRow">
               <strong>$59,549.16</strong>
               <div class="wrapStat">
                    <span class="pastStat">($59,799.66)</span>
                    <img src="https://portal.thesba.com/Images/down_arr.gif" alt="decrease">
                    <span class="decreasedStat">0.42%</span>
               </div>
          </div>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Nice, glad you got it worked out. So, do I get your bounty for my effort? :)

Comment: from my previous comment: there's no reason to have divs (block by default) inside of strongs (inline by default) inside of spans (inline) inside of td's (block). i think if you simplify and clean up your markup the problem will go away. good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I did some testing and wasn't able to reproduce the problem. Have you tried testing the mobile debugging feature on jsfiddle?

I put together the following simple example.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="changeMe">Hello World</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.portrait {
    display: block !important;
}
.landscape {
    display: inline !important;
}
#changeMe {
    color: blue;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('orientationchange', function() {
        console.log('updated orientation: ' + window.orientation);

        if (window.orientation == 0) {
            // portrait mode
            $('#changeMe').removeClass('landscape').addClass('portrait').text('Portrait Mode');
        } else {
            // landscape mode
            $('#changeMe').removeClass('portrait').addClass('landscape').text('Landscape Mode');
        }
    });

});​
```

Here is a link to the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gizmovation/9ALTU/

When you use the mobile debugging feature (the little wifi looking icon next to the run button), you can open the page on your iphone while simultaneously debugging on your PC. When I did this, I was able to see that the block and inline styles were toggling properly on the #changeMe div. This should work regardless of whether the content was loaded via ajax.

Hope this helps and that you are able to use the mobile debugger to resolve your issue.

Comment: +1 for the jsFiddle Mobile tip...
Here is the jsFiddle of the code actually not working...

http://jsfiddle.net/Hupperware/43eK8/5/

Mobile view: http://jsfiddle.net/m/rat/

This works in Firefox (text turns red in "landscape" and blue in "portrait" just so you know it's working). In FF it will show inline and block as you go between a wider view and a narrow view...

In Webkit (Safari and Chrome) it will not...

Comment: I tried out your sample on my iphone and I didn't notice anything changing, but I think it must be due to another issue. It actually crashed my phone browser a couple times. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/gizmovation/tV8p4/ and mobile view: http://jsfiddle.net/m/mzw/. Try opening the mobile view on your phone and changing the orientation. The list items go from block to inline. This is the issue, right? I would assume if it works here that you can make yours work also. If you can break down your sample into something much smaller maybe I can offer further assistance.

Comment: It's the grid headings that is the issue under the Credit Card Txns collapsible. The heading Total Sales moves (just like it did in mine) and the color changes (also like mine) but the stats that are in blue should move up (.wrapStat) to be inline with the black stat and turn red... this isn't happening in either version. It's strictly the stats lines that aren't behaving in WebKit.

Comment: Ok, I was able to see the color changing. I trimmed your example: http://jsfiddle.net/gizmovation/SCXf6/ When I open the mobile view on my iphone and change orientation, I get both a color change and a shift in layout. I looked at the debugger and the inline/block display is getting toggled. Do you see the layout shift? Also, please let me know how you are testing this.

Comment: I'm testing it through the jsfiddle mobile option on my iPhone. Even with the trimmed down example the layout shifts but the inline/block of tags wrapStat are still not working. The money figures next to the Total Sales heading are supposed to be on 1 line in landscape mode and separate lines in portrait mode. This broken behavior I'm only seeing in webkit browsers.

Comment: I understand what you want it to do, but I think it is the structure of your html that is causing the discrepancy, not the inability for webkit browsers to handle inline/block changes (that would be a HUGE issue). Perhaps you can try running your page through the w3cvalidator: http://validator.w3.org/ and see what it comes up with.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `!important` from both your css classes.

Comment: I've done that. I don't believe it's a css issue. I think it's webkit not liking the switch between block and inline without a content refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say about webkit handling in browser. What I can say is that orientationchange is detected differently across devices and browsers. This can cause headaches...  ([example](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/orientationchange-event-returns-wrong-values-on-android)).

Last time I pulled my hair out because Android always returned the "wrong" orientation (portrait in landscape, landscape in portrait), when iOS reported it the other way around.

That's why [JQM recommends](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) to bind to **resize** instead of **orientationchange** when working with width/height and orientationchange. Resize will fire together with every orientationchange, so you are independent of browser implementation of the event.

So my first suggestion would be: Can you bind to resize instead?

If you want to stick with orientationchange, here is a script I'm using, which seems to work ok:

```
// trigger 
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(event){
      your_function(event);
      });

// function handling orientation
function  your_function(event) {
    ...
    if ( event ) {
        // portrait
        if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180 ){
                // portrait stuff
        }
        // landscape
            else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90 ) {
                // landscape stuff
                }
        // any other event that's passed into here, you could feed RESIZE
        } else if ( $window.width() < THRESHOLD WIDTH) {
                // portrait stuff
                } else if ($window.width() > THRESHHOLD WIDTH) {
                          // landscape stuff
                          }
               }
```

Right now, I'm only feeding orientationchange into this function and it seems to work ok. If it wouldn't, I could also change to triggering this on resize and NOT passing the event like so:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
     your_function("I'm no event");
     });
```

which will end up in the 2nd handler. You would need a threshold width (600px?) though at which the layout should change.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't get is the `if ($(window).width() > 600) return;` you don't want to target high rez devices?

I may be wrong but doesn't it end this event hanling function if paysage and most recnt android and iphone (> HVGA and Iphone retina)?

Comment: There are two different views. I don't want this logic used for tablets. It's always inline.

Comment: I'm ok for tablets, but all recent devices have 1 or 2 dimensions higher than 600px (ex Iphone 4S 960 * 640) so you block the event for every devices other than old ones.

Answer (score 0):

your html that you pasted above is messed up. you have an unclosed strong tag. you probably shouldn't have a strong tag at all, or if you do, put it inside the div, not outside. you have at tr wrapped in a span. this is very syntactically incorrect, i'm not surprised at all it doesn't render reliably. a span is inline by default, and then you put a tr inside of an inline element. how would you expect this to render? if you can, try to remove the tr's and td's entirely and just use floated divs instead. if you absolutely need to use a table, then build the table correctly. try to simplify the markup. the more complicated the markup, the more room for error. if you have multiple markup errors, different browsers may handle the poor markup in different ways. there's no reason to have divs (block by default) inside of strongs (inline by default) inside of spans (inline) inside of td's (block). i think if you simplify and clean up your markup the problem will go away. good luck.

Comment: This was pulled from a page render and truncated. The td block is nested correctly as the jsFiddles show. Thanks for looking at the issue.